# How to remove ngClass while widening the screen

Tags: angular, angular-ng-class

I am adding a class to 2 div to toggle sidebar header using `[ngClass]` how do i remove those class when enlarge the screen.

[image]

The problem is on widening the screen it remains there only because class is not removed. How do i remove the class?

On adding class `[ngClass]="{'menu-push-onscreen': show}"` it will toggle and when i widen screen it will be there itself how shall i remove that?

```
show: boolean = false;

 onToggleHeader(){
   this.show=!this.show;
```

}

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question. This helps people give better answers by understanding what you have tried and where you may be going wrong.

Comment: @Samson make use of mediaQueries of CSS

Comment: please tell me the media queries for 1024px @RahulSingh

Comment: @Samson updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the [ngClass] binding to null. Here is an example:

In your component.html:

```
<div [ngClass]="myClass"></div>
```

In your component class:

```
...
// Declare varibale
myClass:string;

// Set some variable to true if the screen widening
if(isScreenWidening){
    this.myClass = null;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { // this is for screen width less than equal to 600px

  .yourClass{
     // remove all the properties you might have set
  }
}
```

If you need to add more media queries as per screen size change the max or min width.